# Dispose graphic element in Paint eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, dispose

I am working with C#, .net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

After some reading about when I do have to dispose elements I am a bit confused. Would the following Paint eventhandler be ok, or would it be a Memory leak?

```
private void ProgressBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        string rightText = "rightext";
        string leftText = "lefttext";;
        string textToDraw = rightText + leftText;
        graphics.DrawString(textToDraw, progressBar.Font, 
             new SolidBrush(progressBar.ForeColor), 10, 30);                         
    }
```

Would this work fine then?

```
private void ProgressBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        string rightText = "rightext";
        string leftText = "lefttext";;
        string textToDraw = rightText + leftText;
        using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(progressBar.ForeColor)) {
            graphics.DrawString(textToDraw, progressBar.Font, solidBrush, 18, 20);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say the second method is probably better. However, this belongs on CodeReview, not on SO I think

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - no, this is about rsrc management in a specific API, not about coding style.

Comment: As a general rule, when a Type implements IDisposable then use `using(){}`. Unless you have a very clear reason not to.

Comment: Ok I guess I see that. It seemed to be a 'which one is better' and that was it. But after re-reading I can see that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first snippet has a bug, plain and simple.  You really should dispose that brush.  If you don't then you completely depend on the finalizer to take care of it.  Which is a bit slow at getting the job done, it can only run after a garbage collection was done.

Particularly a problem for a progress bar style control, it tends to paint itself at a high rate. Much more so than normal controls since there's, well, lots of progress if you wrote good code.  If the garbage collector cannot keep up and cleanup those brushes for you then your program will crash.  Happens when there are almost ten thousand brushes that need finalized, the operating system stops your program from creating more of them, kaboom.

Answer (score 2):

The second method prevents memory leaking on your brush. Every object that derives from `IDisposable` that is not reused after exiting the method should be disposed. (Note that if you dispose it and then try to access it, it's most likely in a unusable, faulted state and you most likely get an exception on that).

The preferred way to dispose an object is using a `using` statement.